# Debug Flash Player is NOT showing error popups

Tags: flash, flashplayer-debug

I have installed the debug flash player for my mac, as explained in various articles. The problem I have is that the player doesn't show the errors - which I as a tester need to see.
[Version check](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html) tells me that I have MAC 10,2,153,1 both in Chrome 11.0.696.71 and Firefox 4.0.1. In Chrome I have disabled the built-in Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin and enabled the debug plugin I installed. The only hint I have that something is wrong is that when I right-click on a flash content then the Debugger item is inactive in the context menu. As I have uninstalled and re-installed the plugin many times in the last months, I am really clueless now what the problem could be. I would be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `mm.cfg` file for `SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1` which suppresses the exception dialogs, as the name implies.  I had this in my `mm.cfg` file and have no idea how it got there.

Setting the value to `0` fixed it.

On a Mac the `mm.cfg` files is at `/Library/Application Support/Macromedia`
More info at

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html

http://www.senocular.com/?entry=475

http://jpauclair.net/mm-cfg-secrets/

Comment: Samuel, this solved my issue. The file was in my home folder, and I also don't know how it got there. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

My debugger **is working** on a mac dev chrome (and I just installed it for the first time), but the `Debugger` item in the content menu is also "inactive", or grayed out. I don't think that's a sign it's anything right or wrong. Here, this is [also](http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2010/4/27/Configuring-Chrome-with-Flash-Player-Debugger#responseresult) how my `chrome://plugin` is setup: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/screenshot20110613at161.png/ and your [version check link](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html) gives me a **Debug Player: Yes**, right below my player version and before OS details.

I can only bet it's something wrong with your specific chrome / flash installation (have you double checked the flash installed **path**?) or with chrome 11 and the new flash, since I'm using the 12.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the same setup in Chrome as shown in your screenshot. Plus I also have the problem in Firefox.

Comment: @peetasan which points towards the flash installation issue. And since reinstalling didn't solve it, you'd have to go deeper and begin by checking the installation paths. You can try to first uninstall everything you have from flash, remove it all have it clean. Then install it. That's not the same as installing it on top of a broken installation.

Answer (score -1):

There is also one issue with overriding SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs to 1.
I had flashbug plugin installed in firefox and everytime firefox was restarted flashbug was assigning 1 to this option. after removing this plugin debugging started to work.